# cc1 has stopped working [compiling and executing in notepad++]

Tags: c, compilation, notepad++

I am trying to compile and execute c code using notepad++.

Below is the script i am using for NppExec.

```
NPP_SAVE
SET GCC = C:\cygwin\bin\gcc.exe
SET OBJ = $(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)\$(NAME_PART)
"$(GCC)" -c "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)" -o "$(OBJ).o"
"$(GCC)" "$(OBJ).o" -o "$(OBJ).exe" 
"$(OBJ).exe"
UNSET OBJ
UNSET GCC
```

when I execute above script using F6. I get below messages.

```
# NPP_EXEC: "C_compile_execute"  
# NPP_SAVE: E:\Cprograms\test.c  
# SET: GCC = C:\cygwin\bin\gcc.exe  
# $(GCC) = C:\cygwin\bin\gcc.exe  
# SET: OBJ = E:\Cprograms\test  
# $(OBJ) = E:\Cprograms\test  
# "C:\cygwin\bin\gcc.exe" -c "E:\Cprograms\test.c" -o "E:\Cprograms\test.o"  
# Process started >>>  
# <<< Process finished.  
# "C:\cygwin\bin\gcc.exe" "E:\Cprograms\test.o" -o "E:\Cprograms\test.exe"  
# Process started >>>  
# gcc: E:\Cprograms\test.o: No such file or directory  
# gcc: no input files  
# <<< Process finished.  
# "E:\Cprograms\test.exe"  
# CreateProcess() failed with error code 2:  
# The system cannot find the file specified.  

# - the user's variable has been removed: $(OBJ)  
# - the user's variable has been removed: $(GCC)  
# ================ READY ================
```

And I got a error in popup window like: "cc1 has stopped working"

However, I can compile and execute from commandline successfully.

```
E:\Cprograms>C:\cygwin/bin/gcc.exe test.c -o test.exe

E:\Cprograms>test.exe
Hello
E:\Cprograms>
```

I am using Windows Vista.

Please guide me on how I can I solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

You need to protect (escape or quote) the backslashes. Notice how the colon (the character after the backslash) is missing in the output, that's your hint.